# GCM push notifications doesn't work after restart device

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have an app on Android with push notifications using GCM. When I turn on the app and go back to menu/lock device it works perfectly. The problem is when I reset phone or dont use app for a long time - notifications dont come. Do have any ideas why?

Comment: This may be slightly relevant to the issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011981/gcm-not-delivery-if-internet-off/35027841#35027841. Basically there's a lot of factors that can be attributed to this. Its possible that since the app is restarted, the service in your application that handles GCM hasn't started yet. Also, check out if you've implemented a broadcast receiver. you can look at an issue relating to it [in this ticket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269039/gcm-broadcast-receiver-onreciever-is-not-called)

Comment: Could you post your Android code that is receiving the notification?